# iGrid should not jump to col at a click

Tags: winforms, igrid

I'm using iGrid.NET.

If the columns are bigger than the available space, a scrollbar is shown:

[image]

Now when I click on a column which is partly outside the visible area, the clicked column is shown at the left start:

[image]

I know it's unusual, but I would like the scrollbar to stay exactely where it is.
I want to have col 1 shown on the left.

How could I do this?

Comment: I don't know iGrid.NET, but it appears that with ListView, you wouldn't have the issue. Would there be any inconveniences by using ListView instead?

Comment: @Sideways Thank you, but I have intentionally abandoned ListView, I couldn't customize it enough.

Comment: Only thing I could think of is a workaround, since I don't know iGrid.NET, as mentioned. You could wrap the grid inside a panel with auto scroll enabled, and then extend the grid's width to fit all columns. This would in a horizontal scrollbar being able to scroll through the list, whilst not jumping to elements. Or use a seperate HScrollBar which changes its position. Whilst these possibilities are not very clean compared to other ways, these can still be implemented without one being able to notice at all.